# share content on facebook from web service

Tags: facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api

I have a REST web service written in PHP that is part of a web site. This web site has users that can post data where have they traveled and rate the place. Mobile app. uses the web service to submit the travel details.

Can a user share his "travel data" on Facebook trough web service?

**Goal, Use Case:**
User on his phone selects a country, city .... rate it and submit the data, data is sent to web service that writes this data to DB and shared it on Facebook as the user of the web site that has FB membership).

**Assumptions:**
User should loggin trough the site and request a "permanent" token from Facebook, store it in DB.user_settings, use the token when data is sent from mobile app.
**Update**: Or, collect users FB username/pass in DB.user_settings and authenticate when web service method for posting data on FB is called.

**Problem:** 
Token is not "permanent"

How to authenticate the user, and not send any credentials from the mobile app. concerning Facebook, but keep all the FB logic in web service?

(im interested in concept design/algorithm, not code)

Comment: For this kind of scenario I suggest you to give a look at the [Open Graph specification](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Comment: Hello Casper  , did you get the solution for this? If Yes, Can you please help me.

Comment: @MadhuP - On the website I have made a button for authenticating against FB, once approved, I store the token i DB and use it in my REST WebService. The only problem was that the token was (maybe still is) not permanent, so I had to check every time you load the page if the token is valid, if it is not I show a button "approve posting on FB". Now, if you dont visit the site for a long time, postings from mob app will fail. I haven't solved this problem, I changed jobs....

Comment: Thanks a lot @DrCasperBlack